# How can I hide or show a different IP to a website?

Tags: software-recommendation, ip

I'd like to watch BBC Iplayer...but it only works in the UK. I am currently living in Spain. Is there a way to hide my ID and make the bbc website believe that I have a UK IP or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### [Stealthy](http://www.stealthy.co/)

This browser plugin comes for Firefox and Chrome/Chromium to enable us to fake an IP from a different country which is then presented to a website we browse to via a proxy provided from stealty.

In the free version there is a somewhat limited capability for choosing our location either as random or for a given country by surfing via a proxy when available there. There also is a commercial PRO version to have an guaranteed IP from the UK or from the USA.

- [Stealthy for Chrome/Chromium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search-extensions/stealthy)
- [Stealthy for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/stealthy/)

Of course there are some security issues we will have to think about when trusting our data to a not so well defined proxy somewhere in the world wide web.

The plugin can easily be switched on or off on demand.

Comment: I'd like to know why I can't even enter in bbc.co.uk/doctorwho after installing this plugin.

Comment: @Zignd: they may have a different approach to find out where you live - unfortunately then we can't use this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Not specific to Ubuntu (It works on Linux / Windows / Mac OSX / iOS but you can use a VPN service that lets you connect to a VPN server in the UK.

Here's one I have used before they let you choose a VPN server in a variety of countrys including the UK.

[VPNUK](https://vpnuk.info/)

Comment: thanks Stephen. I can see that their service costs money. Is there a way to do this for free?

Comment: @Elysium http://uk.newfreevpn.com/ I just googled free vpn server uk and got this, Please bear in mind privacy, when you use a vpn server i'd be wary of any 3rd party VPN server let alone a free one, Just use it to watch video do not do anything else.. banking etc....

Answer (score 0):

You should also use Tor. Tor is an anonymizing service/network with is more secure/anonymous than a VPN.

Tor comes bundled with a browser and GUI interface for easy use

Tor browser bundle: https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en

Also checkout how Tor works, its quite cool: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network)

Comment: How do you choose an exit node in the UK for Tor?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using this [Hide IP on Linux](https://myiphide.com/linux.html)
Just use below 2 commands only (according to given in above link)

- `wget http://myiphide.com/mih`
- `sh mih`

Now you can watch anything or do `torrent`ing without any worry .