# How to hide/change my IP adress

Tags: networking, server

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 and I'm not very educated about it. Can you describe to me what is the easiest way to hide or change my IP adress while I'm using my browser ( Chromium ).

Comment: IP sharing is very common (e.g. in a big company) and most likely not the cause for your problems. But that depends of course on the "some places" you mention. It would be helpful if you'd be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Plumo. From here, I cant register on some internet forums and sites. From other places, I can do it without problems. But again, when I try to log in on those forums from here, I have been blocked before I even post. I believe that IP adress I'm using is compromised. So I want to change or hide IP adress somehow, can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: **Please be more specific**. "some internet forums and sites" is not enough to help you. And please tell exactly what happens when trying to register or login or whenever it fails. Maybe some error message or screenshot would be helpful (e.g. screenshot from Developer Tools -> Network and Console Tabs). Otherwise your question is not answerable and will be closed. Imo it's 99,9% sure that your public IP is not the cause. Don't add useful information in comments but edit your question to include these details.

Comment: See this [How can I hide or show a different IP to a website?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230319/how-can-i-hide-or-show-a-different-ip-to-a-website)

Comment: Also see this: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a VPN, such as NordVPN, Private Internet Access, etc... For a monthly subscribtion (Around 3$/month).

Or you can use the Tor Network, which is free but very slow.

Comment: But TOR or a VPN service won't help with OPs original "problem" (see original question in edit history). When using a VPN, you share the IP with even more people o0 ... BTW: There is also "free" VPN, free as in *"I pay with my data"*.

Comment: I didn't talk about the free VPN because of the privacy concerns.
I believe that a VPN would be a solution to OP's problem, since the server would only see the VPN's IP, and thus not block his. What do you mean 'You share your IP with even more people?'

Comment: Sorry, I'm refering to the original question, which you cannot see I think because you don't have enogh reputation to see the edit history.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm new here, my bad :D